# APP_INITIALIZER with observable in standalone component

Tags: angular

I am trying to make fetch some data during app initialization using APP_INITIALIZER DI token  similar to the example provided by Angular.

**Minimum reproducible example:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-igrwzv?file=src%2Fmain.ts

**Example from Angular documentation:**

```
function initializeAppFactory(httpClient: HttpClient): () => Observable<any> {
 return () => httpClient.get("https://someUrl.com/api/user")
   .pipe(
      tap(user => { ... })
   );
}
```

From Angular documentation:

> If any of these functions returns a Promise or an Observable,
> initialization does not complete until the Promise is resolved or the
> Observable is completed

Hence, I am calling `take(1)`, so that the observable completes. But I don't see the REST API being called.

```
export function initializeApplication(http: HttpClient) {
  return (): Observable<any> =>
    http.get('https://651ec54444a3a8aa4768fa35.mockapi.io/user').pipe(
      take(1),
      tap((data) => console.log(data)) // Why is this not getting executed?
    );
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.io/start">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeApplication,
      multi: true,
      deps: [HttpClient],
    },
  ],
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You need to provide it before first component even initializes

```
export function initializeApplication(http: HttpClient) {
  return (): Observable<any> =>
    http.get('https://651ec54444a3a8aa4768fa35.mockapi.io/user').pipe(
      take(1),
      tap((data) => console.log(data)) // Why is this not getting executed?
    );
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.io/start">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(),
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeApplication,
      multi: true,
      deps: [HttpClient],
    },
  ],
});
```

Comment: Angular isn't able to find provider for HttpClient: `ERROR
Error: R3InjectorError(Environment Injector)[ApplicationInitStatus -> InjectionToken Application Initializer -> [object Object] -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!`  

See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jtfbjw?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: provideHttpClient()  needs to be added to providers array.